# How do I formulate find() based on multiple _ids?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, find

I am trying retrieve two objects based on their two Object _ids.

As demonstrated in the code below, my **Session.get();** function retrieves the two **_id**, that I use in my query.

```
 var selectedID = Session.get('selectedItemIDSet');
 selectedID = selectedID.toString();
 selectedID = selectedID.split(","); 

 alert(selectedID);
```

**The alert above pops out two _ids : LZJKA8S3wYNwHakzE, ikrbCDuttHrwkEcuv**

```
 console.log("selectedID is: ",...selectedID);
```

The above console() function also yeilds:

**selectedID is:  LZJKA8S3wYNwHakzE  ikrbCDuttHrwkEcuv**

```
 buyList.find({_id:{ "$in": selectedID} }).fetch();
```

The query above only returns One object, namely Object with **_id: "LZJKA8S3wYNwHakzE"** and not TWO Objects which would be the expected results.

Just to clarify, the expected result should be TWO Objects with **_ids: LZJKA8S3wYNwHakzE, ikrbCDuttHrwkEcuv**

Kindly point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: your split() should create an array of strings. is it creating an array or something else? your output makes it look like it's not an array.

Comment: @zim  thanks for pointing this out. I resolved it by split() making the string an array before the Session.set() function instead. It's now working as desired.